# 2000 dodge caravan won't start

Tags: starting, dodge, caravan

A few days ago I was driving and the battery light came on on the dash. I pulled over (it was raining). So the defroster was on and lights. All at once the radio light went off and my van felt like it was going to stall and it did. When someone attempted to give me a jump so I could get it home, they connected the neg before the positive in which there was a spark on the terminal. No fire or explosion (thank god). But connected jumpers the right way and got it home. Now it won't start. I replaced the battery and the alternator and starter are less than 6 mths old. Van sounds so close to starting but just won't. Any answers or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Was the alternator/starter installed properly? Could something have jiggled loose or got cut by the belts (belts that connect crank to alternator, ac, etc) that would lead to a short? Best to inspect the wires running to these components fully to see if they could be grounding out anywhere (creating a short)

Comment: Codes in any of the modules? Have you checked the fuses with a multimeter?

Comment: Sounds like the alternator has failed again, charge the battery then start and test alternator output with a voltmeter, it should output over 14 volts DC.

Answer (score 2):

Switched a couple fuses. And it started. Battery is new and charged. Was able to get the van to auto zone and have it tested. It is the alternator! Thanks everyone

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to let us know what worked for you. Glad to hear you got it sorted!! =]